# Can Node.js fully replace solutions like Apache or NGINX?

Tags: node.js

About deploying a Node.js application, I have seen a lot of tutorials showing it deployed side-by-side with Nginx, with more or less pretty tricks to allow the 2 to work together (and annoying stuff, like Nginx not supporting WebSockets). This seems a bit complicated to me ...

Why does everybody do this kind of setup ?
Does deploying Nginx when you have Node.js provide any advantage ?
Can't you serve static files with Node.js ?

I've written a lot of apps in Django, and the doc says that you shouldn't use Django to serve static files cause it's not optimized for this and so on ... so I was thinking maybe this is the reason.

Comment: I have the same question. They still use nginx for gateway purposes and express for server purposes. I think if you want a nodejs gateway, you can consider redbird instead of nginx. I think it fully supports websockets as well. In my case I did not find any real purpose to use nginx or a gateway, so I will use express only.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well some people don't mind using Node instead of nginx. 
Certain clouds like [dotCloud](http://dotcloud.com) or [Nodejistu](http://www.nodejit.su) uses gateways entirely written in Node.js. Mostly to be able to handle websockets. But also because Node.js is damn fast.

Here is the gateway of dotCloud which has been open sourced recently https://github.com/dotcloud/hipache

Comment: So there's nothing wrong in doing that right ? Do you happen to know any node package that would help serve an entire directory, a bit like you could do with Nginx ?

Comment: To just deliver static files Node does not provide any real advantages over nginx. In the case of a gateway that needs to dynamically route HTTP traffic around multiple host and support websockets Node might be the best tool out there.

Comment: So personally I would not mind delivering static content through Express for example. But I would not use Node just to deliver static content Nginx has been made to be the best for that. I philosophy is to always use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @sebpiq If you're using express, the inbuilt 'static' middleware does exactly this.

Answer (score 28):

Both Apache and NGINX are fully developed web servers offering lots of modules and services out of the box. They're considered robust and has proven stability for several years now.

Having that sort of available solutions, there's no need to re-invent the wheel. It can be more beneficial to implement the load balancer and routing with NGINX and not expose NodeJS to the outside and just run it on localhost.

NodeJS can't be considered a server software but merely a JavaScript engine plus libraries/modules. The fact that it's heavily used for server scripting does not make it web server.

If you decide to overlook the above and switch to NodeJS completely, i offer you think about maintaining such a solution. Logging, startup/shutdown scripts and monitoring can make the task more complicated than it seems.

Further more, numerous libraries written for NodeJS tend to break with new versions delivered, as breaking changes are introduced by NodeJS. Consider that as the price for the lack of maturity. If you're up to the risk and not afraid of problems, go for NodeJS.

*Final note: static files can be served with NodeJS. Your scripts may read it and push it out.*

Update: If you decided to go for Node.js consider to use Express.js framework.

Comment: Well ... node is a tool to build web servers cf node.js website : "Node.js is a platform [...] for easily building fast, scalable network applications." I don't see a problem with exposing your node.js app "outside" !?

Comment: In theory everything can be programmed in Node.js. However, Node doesn't (yet) have the maturity of Apache or Nginx. What node instead offers is tremendous flexibility in building application servers due to the Javascript libraries (many many developers) and its rapid upgrade cycle. Unfortunately, this approach also leads to potential security and scalability (in the libraries at least) issues. So take the best of both worlds, let Apache/Nginx do what they are really good at doing - proxies and loadbalancing for example, and then use Node to build amazing apps the world can drool over.

Comment: 'NodeJS can't be considered a server software but merely a JavaScript framework. The fact that it's heavily used for server scripting does not make it web server.' that's provably false. Node does its low level socket handling in C just like nginx does, and implements streams, async io and other low level concepts.

Comment: Nodejs not written in C. Its written in C++ Google's Javascript Engine V8 enhanced with non blocking I/O like Eventlib.
Nodejs simply runs javascript but use kernel low level API events for callback.

Comment: NGINX(Reverse Proxy server written in C) written in 2002 by sysadmin Igor Sysoev to speedup Rambler Apache based websites (biggest internet provider in Russia that time) 
NGINX and NodeJS have nothing common. (except eventlib). NGINX still used in pair with Apache when people like Apache's features like mod_php or others. 
NGNIX basics is caching response and unload slow apache server by quickly responding with cached value.

Comment: Of course now its more developed and supporting WSGI(for Python) and FastCGI(for PHP) but initial idea was to make Apache faster thats all(as Sysoev looked through Apache source code and written mod_accel and mod_deflate for Apache).

Comment: This actually answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using only node.js for the whole thing. The reason for that is, that many node applications have built-in file servers or depend on one that serves their files. So, every application can use the fileserver that fits best and can customize it to its needs.

Additionally, you lose a bit of performance when you have to proxy every single request from Apache/NGINX to node.js. It's much simpler to let node handle the requests by itself.

Comment: You lose a lot of performance when you try to serve static files, do load balancing and handle virtual server configuration in javascript.

Comment: I would be curious to know why you think that you lose performance for those things. Static files, OK, maybe. But load balancing and virtual server configuration—if you need dynamic reconfiguration, you are generally better with a custom reverse proxy like Hipache, rather than Apache or Nginx which require a full restart each time you change something. Been there, done that, switched to Node.js once we reached tens of thousands of virtual hosts and Nginx took almost one minute to reload its configuration...

Comment: @jpetazzo I noticed that if I use proxies in front of my application, I get more latency (which was really bad for my websocket-based multiplayer game). Therefore I developed node-ancillary, which passes the socket between processes, instead of proxying which gives me nice performance. I never said that you shouldn't load balance, but you don't have to use NGINX or Apache for that. Node.js can do much cooler things.

Comment: hipache commited on github 2 month ago. Its hard to say its stable and mature project.

Comment: @VanCoding Yes, I agree with you—I was questioning the reasoning of VBart, sorry if this was misleading :-)

Comment: @Whity we have a large hipache cluster in production since 3+ months (we've been using it extensively before open-sourcing it); each node of the cluster is serving a few thousands of hits per second, and has a few thousands of WebSocket connections open at any time. It's certainly not as mature as Nginx or Apache, and it's certainly not bug-free, but I wouldn't be ashamed to call it "stable" or "production-ready"! :-)