# Can Node.js + express + socket.io + pm2 completely replace Nginx in handling large concurrent requests?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io, pm2

I have read [Can Node.js fully replace solutions like Apache or NGINX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050704/can-node-js-fully-replace-solutions-like-apache-or-nginx) , the reason i'm asking this question is because Node.Js has matured a lot and so has Nginx since that question has been asked. So my question is this "Can **Node.Js + express + socket.io + pm2**  replace **Nginx**'s capability to handle large concurrent requests?". 

Note: I know Nginx is a server software and Node.Js is a programming language, they can't be compared, they can be used by reverse proxying etc., but i want to know in terms of concurrent request handling, load balancing.

Comment: Probably you can replace, but better question if you should do that. Those are not dummy requests right? So more requests you have more load is in your server, hence the requirement of scaling and you shouldnt use nodejs as public facing node for traffice redirection, load balancing, health checks etc across your cluster

Comment: I want to know why I should not use it? Please elaborate your answers in technical terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure it can. It is not the best practice, but it can. Best practice will be to serve static assets from nginx, and everything else from node. But nothing prevents you to use only node. It is only matter of optimization.

Comment: Can node.js be optimized to serve static assets, whose performance can be eqaul to nginx

Comment: Try and let us know the result :-)

Comment: :D sure I will try